# Migrating PostGIS spatial data to SQL Server Spatial

Tags: postgis, sql-server, software-recommendations, spatial-etl

I am trying to migrate PostGIS geometry to SQL Server Spatial data. It's the first time I'll work with SQL Server Spatial.

Is there any Data ETL model that does this migration?

Comment: There are multiple ETL applications mentioned here: [Spatial ETL comparisons](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5049/spatial-etl-comparisons)

Answer (score 5):

You can try

- pgsql2shp (shapefile intermediate) and then use the sqlspatialtools to load
- OGR2OGR supports reading and writing at both ends of that pipe
- part of me wants to suggest that a PG_DUMP to text would provide SQL that could then be consumed in SQL server.

Details click [here](http://postgis.17.n6.nabble.com/Moving-Migrating-PostGIS-9-1-with-Geometry-to-MS-SQL-2008-td4999083.html)

Answer (score 2):

try to use program [brigantine](http://code.google.com/p/brigantine/) to migrate PostGIS geometry to SQL server Spatial data

Comment: I really dont know how this piece of software can help someone to migrate PostGIS spatial data to MsSql spatial data. It looks just like a simple GIS viewer and there is no even basic manual...

Comment: very cool spartan program, you just copy/paste layers between servers, and it does the rest for you

Answer (score 0):

From

http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/index.php?/archives/31-GDALOGR2OGR-for-Data-Loading.html

---

**Microsoft SQL Server (and other ODBC) to PostgreSQL**

OGR has a driver that supports ODBC DSN connections. Unfortunately this will only work on Windows. Below is an example that imports all tables from a SQL Server database to PostgreSQL. In this example, the DSN I have is using NT Authentication or has the name and password encoded in the System DSN. For this you need to setup a DSN connection to the SQL Server database in ODBC Manager (we described setting up a DSN in Using MS Access with PostgreSQL, except the ODBC driver seems to only work with System DSNs not File DSNs. For more details on referencing the ODBC DSN - check http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_odbc.html

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=pghost user=pgloginname dbname=pgdbname password=pgpassword" 
"ODBC:system_dsn_goes_here" -update -lco OVERWRITE=yes -nlt NONE
```

As noted, geometry fields seem to be created and right field types are not necessarily created. SQL Server text come in as VARCHARS and VARCHARS come in as CHARS etc. One way to get around this is to create your table structures before hand and use OGR2OGR to just load the data.

E.g.

--This will append to a table called orders reading from the SQL Server (ODBC) table orders and customers.  It will only append like-named fields.

```
psql -h pghost -p 5432 -U pguser -d pgdbname -c "TRUNCATE TABLE orders;TRUNCATE TABLE customers;"

ogr2ogr -append -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=pghost user=pgloginname dbname=pgdbname password=pgpassword port=5432" 
"ODBC:system_dsn_goes_here" orders customers
```

Or correct the structures afterword by dropping unnecessary fields using a script generation technique similar to what we described in DML to Generate DDL and DCL. So your script builder SQL to drop all the ogc_fid and wkb_geometry fields created by OGR2OGR would look something like this.

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' || t.table_schema || '.' || t.table_name || ' DROP COLUMN ogc_fid;' 
    FROM information_schema.tables t 
        INNER JOIN information_schema.columns c 
        ON (t.table_name = c.table_name AND t.table_schema = c.table_schema AND c.column_name = 'ogc_fid')
    UNION 
    SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' || t.table_schema || '.' || t.table_name || ' DROP COLUMN wkb_geometry;' 
    FROM information_schema.tables t 
    INNER JOIN information_schema.columns c 
    ON (t.table_name = c.table_name AND t.table_schema = c.table_schema AND c.column_name = 'wkb_geometry';
```