# Spatial ETL for MutliLineString

Tags: postgis, geometry, spatial-etl, geokettle

I'm pretty new to Spatial ETL.

In accordance with this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5049/seeking-options-for-spatial-etl-extract-transform-load) I have experience the geokettle v3 but unfortunately i'm having a several problems working with it.

There is some issues that aren't being tracked since that geokettle development seems  knowing that:

> ..the future version of GeoKettle will be more pluggable with Kettle and
>   will not be anymore a friendly and spatially enabled fork of Kettle.
>   Hence, it will be possible to add spatial extensions provided by
>   GeoKettle to any Kettle/PDI 5.x installation.

(GeoKettle_readme.txt)

Another issue that i've noticed is that Geokettle only leads with some geometry type like point, line or polygon and doesn't work with multipolygon or multiline.

So my issue is how can i make a Spatial ELT to migrate a PostGIS database with multilinestrings to another one PostGIS database?

I would like to know your experience about Spatial ETL? Anyone have already made a similar process (A spatial ETL with geometry type like MutliLineString) ?

Share your experience with Spatial extension for Talend or another Spatial ETL tool.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using ogr2ogr? It works with multi geometry types and ETL can be automated into batch files and run as schedules tasks.
e.g. To copy a shapefile into PostGIS, specifying EPSG and ensuring the geometry type is multipolygon.

```
c:\OSGeo4W\bin\ogr2ogr.exe -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname=postgis host=localhost user=postgres password=mypostgrespassword active_schema=myschemaname" "myshapefile.shp" -overwrite -a_srs "EPSG:27700" -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI --config PG_USE_COPY YES
```

The code above can be used in a batch file.

The tags used are **-f** specifies the format to convert to, **-overwrite** overwrites the conversion if it already exists (you can use append instead), **-a_srs** sets the spatial reference system,  and many other tags can be used and are are explained on the ogr2ogr web pages.

Comment: Thanks Lee for your prompt answer, i used ogr2ogr for shapefiles but it's not a exactly a copy or a shapefile import what i need. I need to Extract from a Database Transform and Load in another one.