# Can QGIS do automated spatial ETL?

Tags: qgis, spatial-etl

Can QGIS do automated spatial ETL?  ... especially the **automated** point

I'm aware of tools like FME, Talend, etc. but price is a concern, so I'm looking for FOSS alternatives that provide spatial ETL that can be automated/part of a workflow

Also aware of ogr2ogr, but whilst powerful, it's seems to be just a file format converter, rather than a true ETL

An examples of the sort of ETL's we're looking at are ...

- connect to back office application using its SOAP web service and extract list of lampposts, including USRN (Unique Street Reference Number)
- query against LLPG database to get corresponding OS NGR for the USRN
- transform various lookup code field into end-user English
- remove sensitive data fields
- insert into SQL Server spatial table
- alert to configured end points on any issues

And these ETL's should be run on

- scheduled days, times, etc.
- response to external trigger

Comment: You should define "true ETL" more precisely before we can judge what can be done with GDAL and what not. Could you describe a couple of use cases?

Comment: There are a lot of options within ogr2ogr for filtering and merging, so unless you can clarify what you need, this is a bit too open-ended.

Comment: Your use cases seem to require either rather a lot scripting or for a quicker start, some ready made tool. Talend is one alternative and it uses GDAL for geometry stuff http://talend-spatial.github.io/

Comment: Hale Studio is another alternative https://www.wetransform.to/products/halestudio/ source http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5049/seeking-options-for-spatial-etl-extract-transform-load