# Best (Spatial ETL) Tool open Source

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-etl

What is the best Spatial ETL Tool opensource can I use it?

Comment: Find some considerations from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5049/seeking-options-for-spatial-etl-extract-transform-load

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Geo ETL Tools, I recommend GeoKETTLE: http://www.spatialytics.org/projects/geokettle/

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. What is the best choice between these options?(Hale studio-GeoKettle-QGIS/ Next GIS-gvSIG -grass.osgeo)  .  Do you still GeoKETTLE ???

Comment: @GIS_Q Best is very subjective, I mean when you say best, what task do you have in mind to do?  You should edit the question accordingly. Do you actually want to do Extraction Transformation and Loading (ETL), do you want to run batch scripts to do your ETL.  Do you want a GUI, what datasources do you have, what transformations do you want to do?  Do you want to call remote services...

Comment: https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2016EGUGA..1813938K/abstract may be of interest

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply . I have Oracle DBA (DBA 1) contain some of layer (polygon and point ). i want to make this task :

. Make Spatial joining between this layer (polygons-points...etc)
.Make a relationship class between this layer (like arcmap) and specific the primary and foreign key for each
. extract this result to another Oracle DBA (DBA 2) 

Regards,

Comment: @GIS_Q please don't use the comments to add more details to the question, please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/332398/edit) the question