# Geospatial data extraction web application

Tags: gdal, web

I am quite new in coding and wanted to ask if there are some simple examples and source codes with the similar functionality as this website https://maps.canada.ca/czs/index-en.html which basically:

1. a website to display rasters
2. then enables users to select and crop certain area of the raster using either uploading a shapefile or draw bounding box
3. download the cropped raster as certain raster format (.tiff for example)

Comment: The Government of Canada website is using FME Server from safe software https://maps.canada.ca/czs/js/fme-lib/main.js shows the code, software is available for trial and purchase https://www.safe.com/fme/fme-server/ - examples are here https://playground.fmeserver.com/ *disclaimer I have used this software for 10+ years.

Comment: hey Mapperz, aside from the paid solution like FME Server, are there any open source option to do this? I forgot to state it in my question

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5049/seeking-options-for-spatial-etl-extract-transform-load